# Handling Null values

Tags: classification, random-forest, missing-data

I am trying to fit a `RandomForest` model for a binary classification dataset and I have some feature like, the sales for a particular store and yes/no information indicating whether a store subscribed for a special program offered by the company. So the first one is numerical and second is categorical (binary) variable. Now it has many null values. This missing values are not due to any systematic error like some faulty sensor or some missing fields in docs. The values are missing, because they were not shared. So suppose I have to create the model for a particular time period (say entire 2020) and I have the Sales data only from April 2020. So the sales value for Jan-March are missing. Moreover, for the stores I have, some of them do not have sales information at all for some month. This might happen because those stores were not part of business before April. Same applies for that binary variable. Now these are the possible strategies I can apply:

- Replace the missing sales values with some central tendency statistics like median or mode. (But using this will assume that the stores which were not present before April were also part of business)
- Replacing sales values with some special value (like -1). But this might misguide the model. And also, if any return sales are there(negative sales), this approach won't work.
- For the binary variable, I can fill it with some special token like "NULL", but that will require to create one more column in case I need one hot encoding.

What should be the best approach. I am kind of confused and I tried these approaches and all of them give more or less same AUC. Sometimes it reduces a bit.

Comment: The answer actually depends on how many examples you have. If they are enough, a quite drastic approach might be to simply delete all the rows with one or more missing values.

Comment: Perhaps, try a model that can handle nulls such as xgboost